# What's the difference between ...args and arguments in a function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

What's the difference between

```
function(...args) {
  // args is an array
}
```

and

```
function() {
  // arguments is an array-like
}
```

Since it's pretty easy to convert an array-like to array, is there any other differences?

A similar question:

```
myFunction.apply(null, args);
```

and

```
myFunction(...args);
```

Comment: surely [a quick google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript+%22...args%22+vs+arguments&oq=javascript+%22...args%22+vs+arguments) would have worked here? Click first hit, search for "...", information forthcoming?

Comment: @Mike `args` is an arbitrary name, so you might as well just search for *javascript arguments* if you're going to expect the page titled *Arguments object* to address rest parameters. Of course if you know they're called rest parameters, that'd be a better thing to search for.

Comment: I understand it looks easy and I knew most of the things that are answered below. But there are quite a bit of hairy details that are easily missed or misunderstood :) @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: @JMM ... that just makes the point even more? This is an easy thing to google for, searching for documentation on "arguments" will invariably find you mention of "...args" notation in the same documentation.

Comment: @Mike I wouldn't say invariably ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. But sure, the OP could've sought out more information instead of posting. You can say that about a lot of stuff on here though.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I believe we could summarize information on a certain topic here instead of letting people search on the website. Information like this is usually scattered on different web pages and might be hard for people to find.

Comment: @stevemao actually, no. [How to ask a question on Stackoverflow](/help/how-to-ask) explicitly points this out as the very first thing you should do. *Always* search before asking. Because quite often someone else already asked your question *and* got an answer. And if you can't find it, then you search the web. And if you still can't find it, you have a question to ask Stackoverflow.

Comment: The first question is strange because `arguments` is available in both cases.

Answer (score 6):

1. `...args` is new; was not available till ES6
2. You can use it for part of the argument structure: `function(foo, bar, ...others)`
3. You get an array, so no more `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)`
4. `...args` is more obvious to code readers
5. Now that we have matches and lighters, we don't need to rub sticks to make fire

However, as a corollary to 1, [not everything supports it yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rest-parameters).

Answer (score 2):

Re: differences between `apply()` and spread (when passing `null` or such as the `thisArg` to `apply()` as in the example):

```js
myFunction.apply(null, args);
myFunction(...args);
```

Aside from spread being newish, so not as widely supported currently, `apply()` accepts an array or array-like object of arguments, whereas spread will work on any iterable. For example, you could spread a `Set` or `Map` as the arguments while you couldn't pass it as the `argArray` argument to `apply()` (though you could of course spread it as the arguments to `call()`: `myFunction.call(whatever, ...someIterable)`).

> Since it's pretty easy to convert an array-like to array, is there any other differences?

It's not really that easy for `arguments`. Doing it wrong (or perhaps at all) can cause the JS engine to deoptimize the function, and if there is a right way to do it that avoids that it requires annoying boilerplate to do it.

Comment: Thanks! iterables are something that's easy to be misunderstood IMO.